# What is Conductance?

Tags: electromagnetism, material-science, electric-current

What is [conductance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_resistance_and_conductance)? I am being said that conductance is inverse of resistance?I do know that resistance is the opposition to the flow of current but do not get conductance?

> I do know that:it is ease of flow current but my brain doesn't accept it,don't know why

Ain't it so important!Couldn't even find it on wikipedia.

Comment: I think it is more of semantics, than anything. We sometimes use conductance to make equations look nicer.

Answer (score 1):

Draw the graph of $\frac 1 x$ . You can see that it is a decreasing function for positive $x$.
Hence conductance decreases as resistance increases.

We could have defined conductance as any other decreasing function also but $\frac 1 R$ appears in many equations so we defined it that way.

You might want to look at [derivation](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/ohmmic.html) of $J=\sigma E$ to get better insight.

Comment: Should it be conductance increases as resistance decreases

Comment: @Uzair Yes a minor typo.

Answer (score 0):

Conductance is indeed defined as the inverse of resistance.

$$G \equiv \frac{1}{R}$$

To see what this means physically, consider that when the resistance is large (i.e. it is "difficult" for current to get through), then conductance is low, and when resistance is small (i.e. it is "easy" for current to get through), then conductance is high. There's an inverse relationship, so if resistance measures how *hard* it is for current to get through, conductance must measure how *easy*, in a rough sense, it is for current to get through.

This is the origin of the name, after all; conductors are simply materials with low resistance.

Answer (score 0):

The [electrical resistance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_conductance) of an electrical conductor is the opposition to the passage of an electric current through that conductor; the inverse quantity is [electrical conductance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_conductance), the ease at which an electric current passes.

Consider resistance of $0.0001$ ohms, what is $\frac{1}{0.0001}ohms$? It is equal to $10000$ siemens. I hope this helped you in understanding conductance. If not you can comment.

Comment: the inverse must have ohms _in the denominator_, otherwise you say 10k siemens is equal to 10k ohms.

Answer (score -1):

Conductance is the ease at which current flow. By comparing with hydraulic analogy use can easily understand this. Suppose current flowing through a wire (or resistor) is like water flowing through a pipe, and the voltage drop across the wire is like the pressure drop that pushes water through the pipe. Conductance is proportional to how much flow occurs for a given pressure, and resistance is proportional to how much pressure is required to achieve a given flow. (Conductance and resistance are reciprocals.)

Reference: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_resistance_and_conductance)

Comment: Wikipedia isn't so much referenced as it is directly copied.